# How to share (e.g "open source") my PhoneGap based application?

Tags: open-source, cordova

I have a **PhoneGap** based application, written in html upon the **Sencha Touch** platform, and directed at for **iPhone** and **Android** devices.

I want to share my projects, and make it **open source**.

The thing is, I am using many different components in my application, which are already an open source project by themselves (**Sencha Touch** via the GPLv3 license, **PhoneGap**, various Phonegap plugins). I  don't want to re-package these resources because I want to be able to easily update these components in my application, when they update.

One way to do it would be to include only my original code (html) and have instructions (Text file) that explains which version of which framework (PhoneGap, Sencah Touch, Plugins) to use with the code. That would be painful for anybody wanting to run the application.

Any ideas on how to share in a friendlier manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend open sourcing the full working app (if the licensing allows.) That way, other adopters and contributors are much more likely to start with something that works.

They then have the option to update the components if they like. You could provide instructions about how to do that.

For you, it shouldn't be extra work to update the components. There are just more files to include when you push to the open source repository.

[Here](https://github.com/paulb777/AppLaudApp) is a PhoneGap, jQuery Mobile, Android project I open sourced recently.

Comment: You have been the only one to reply, and since I did not find any other, more elegant solutions, I am going with your proposed idea. 

Thanks!